# how to make this lotto program repeatable

Tags: python

hi im creating a lotto program that generates 6 random winning numbers,user will select what type of lotto game they want. My problem how can i make this program to ask another choice from the user after their first choice is executed.

```
from random import randint   

def GrandLotto(number):               
    print("\nYou Choose GrandLotto 6/55")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,55)    
        print(value)   

def MegaLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose MegaLotto 6/45")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,45)    
        print(value) 

def UltraLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose UltraLotto 6/58")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,58)    
        print(value)    

def SuperLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose SuperLotto 6/49")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,49)    
        print(value)   

def Lotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose Lotto 6/42")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,42)    
        print(value)   

def main():    

    print("\tLOTTO GAME")    
    number =0    
    print("[1]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[2]=MegaLotto 6/55")    
    print("[3]=UltraLotto 6/58\n[4]=SuperLotto 6/4")    
    print("[5]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[6]=EXIT")    
    choice = eval(input("What is you Choice : "))    
    if(choice ==1):    
        GrandLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==2):    
         MegaLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==3):    
        UltraLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==4):    
        SuperLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==5):    
        Lotto(number)    
    elif(choice==6):    
        print("Program Closing")                                                                                                                                                           
    else:    
        print("Please Select from the choices above")    

main()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to maje it repeatable?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Here, let me Improve your code

```
from random import randint   

def GrandLotto(number):               
    print("\nYou Choose GrandLotto 6/55")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,55)    
        print(value)   

def MegaLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose MegaLotto 6/45")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,45)    
        print(value) 

def UltraLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose UltraLotto 6/58")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,58)    
        print(value)    

def SuperLotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose SuperLotto 6/49")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,49)    
        print(value)   

def Lotto(number):    
    print("\nYou Choose Lotto 6/42")    
    print("\nWINNING NUMBERS")    
    for number in range(6):    
        value = randint(0,42)    
        print(value)   

def main():    

    print("\tLOTTO GAME")    
    number =0    
    print("[1]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[2]=MegaLotto 6/55")    
    print("[3]=UltraLotto 6/58\n[4]=SuperLotto 6/4")    
    print("[5]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[6]=EXIT")    
    choice = eval(input("What is you Choice : "))    
    if(choice ==1):    
        GrandLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==2):    
         MegaLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==3):    
        UltraLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==4):    
        SuperLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==5):    
        Lotto(number)    
    elif(choice==6):    
        print("Program Closing")                                                                                                                                                           
    else:    
        print("Please Select from the choices above")    

if __name__ == "__main__"
    while True:
        main()
```

I added `__name__ == "__main__"` so this script only will be executed if it's running directly (won't execute if using `import` statement) and I add `while True`, it's basically loop and will never end

Answer (score 0):

You can change your def main() to repeat by adding a while loop and breaking when exiting:

```
def main():    
  while True:
    print("\tLOTTO GAME")    
    number =0    
    print("[1]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[2]=MegaLotto 6/55")    
    print("[3]=UltraLotto 6/58\n[4]=SuperLotto 6/4")    
    print("[5]=GrandLotto 6/55\n[6]=EXIT")    
    choice = eval(input("What is you Choice : "))    
    if(choice ==1):    
        GrandLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==2):    
         MegaLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==3):    
        UltraLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==4):    
        SuperLotto(number)    
    elif(choice==5):    
        Lotto(number)    
    elif(choice==6):    
        print("Program Closing")  
        break                                                                                                                                                         
    else:    
        print("Please Select from the choices above")
```